# Why won't this NetBeans test code link correctly?

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, linker

`header.h` declares a function prototype  `void InitializeTestData();`

`a.c` declares it `void InitializeTestData() { ... }`

`b.c` calls it `InitializeTestData();`

and the GCC linker reports `b.c:108: undefined reference to '_InitializeTestData'`

I must be overlooking something obvious, but what?

`header.h` does have an include guard (and its `#define` is used only in that file).

There are no other preprocessor directives involved ... no `#if` wrapped around the prototype or declaration.

Without me having to post the whole project, can someone suggest something to make me say `d'oh!`?

---

Update:  Netbeans handles it and has no problems with the dozen other files with external functions and data.

---

**Answer**: `a.c` was actually a NetBeans test file. NetBeans handles these differently from other files, since they each need to have an `amain()`. That means that they each have their own Makefile and `b.o` was not linking with `a.o` in that file. Solution, move the declaration to a file `c.c` which is not a Netbeans test file.

Comment: how are you compiling/linking your program ?

Comment: +1 good questions. Netbeans handles it and has no problems with the dozen other files with external functions and data.

Comment: If you create a new Netbeans project, and you copy and paste *just* the code you have shown into that project, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Note that the header does not declare a prototype for the function; it simply says the function exists, returns no values, and has an unspecified argument list.  You need to write: `void InitializeTestData(void);` in the header to provide a prototype.  This is C and not C++.

Comment: Does `a.c` define anything else?  Are those other things being used?  Do you get error messages for them too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you linking `a.o` with `b.o`? Most likely you aren't.

Comment: +1 I would ssupect so - except that Netbeans should be taking care of that.

Comment: Your expectation is pretty clearly incorrect. Look at the link line that is failing. It's exceedingly unlikely that it has a.o on it. Please update your question with *actual* failing link line.

Comment: D'oh!   Seeupdared question for the solution  (btw, that was the copy/pasted failed linker line)

Answer (score 1):

The error is from the linker and it means the reference of the function `InitializeTestData` in `b.o` is not resolved.

The reason is you are not liking `a.o` (which contains the definition)  with the `b.o`.

You need to do:

```
# this will compile both the .c files and also link the resultant .o
gcc -o output a.c b.c
```

or

```
gcc -c a.c                 # get a.o
gcc -c b.c                 # get b.o
gcc -o output a.o b.o      # link them
```

Comment: +1 I aplogiz efo rnot saying that this is a Netbeans project so shoudl be taken care of by the IDE

Answer (score 1):

Something is calling `_InitalizeTestData` (note the underscore), but you probably don't define it in either file. Could you have put an underscore somewhere by mistake, of forgotten to implement that?

Comment: +1 but, iirc, the Linker prefixes an underscore when ressolving externals

Comment: I just tested this on gcc 4.4.4; no underscores

Comment: Some ABIs tack an underscore on the beginning of every symbol defined in C, some don't.  For instance, OSX does and Linux doesn't.

Comment: Interesting. Why do they do that?